# WS02 generates POM but no source code

Tags: java, wso2, stub

Having recently upgraded from WS02 3.1.0 to 5.2.1 I also upgraded the associated axis2 and rampart versions to 1.5 and 1.6.2 respectively.

The WSo2 server runs up and creates my list of services and they are all present on the WSO2 console page.

My problem is that, due to the upgrade (axis2), I now have to regenerate the stubs that support our test harness in order to test those services as some classes/interfaces have changed and methods (e.g. org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.writer.MTOMAwareXMLStreamWriter) are no longer present.

According to the notes left by the originator of the current stubs I need to open the list of services and then copy the WDSL2.0 link. Then open the WDSL2Java page on "Tools", paste the link into the uri field, select the version as 2.0 and generate. This is broadly what the WSO2 help page suggests too.

However, when I follow this procedure, this generates a .zip file which contains only a single .POM file (which has a link to the WSDL file in it).

The "generate" page is showing a set of MAVEN information above it which doesn't appear on the help page explanation.

My project is not MAVEN based so my question is how to get the source files generated in the same manner as they were, seemingly, created with WSO2 version 3. The WSDL2.0 file opens when I enter the URL into a browser and contains the details of the associated classes/methods as expected so that seems to be OK.

Is there some configuration I can tweak to turn off the MAVEN POM generation?

Having spent over a day on this I would really appreciate any help.

Greg

Comment: WS02 3.1.0 to 5.2.1 I ? WSO2 which product?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a solution to this after much experimentation:

1. Start your services with WSO2
2. Login to the WSO2 console web page and list the services
3. From the WSDL2 column copy the link to the WSDL file
4. From the cmd line navigate to axis2/bin
5. Enter WSDL2Java -uri [paste the url of the WSDL file here] -sd adl -wv 2.0 -o [destination folder for the generated code here (optional)]